# In Pandas, whats the equivalent of 'nrows' from read_csv() to be used in read_excel()?

Tags: python, pandas

Want to import only certain range of data from an excel spreadsheet (.xlsm format as it has macros) into a pandas dataframe. 
Was doing it this way:

```
data    = pd.read_excel(filepath, header=0,  skiprows=4, nrows= 20, parse_cols = "A:D")
```

But it seems that nrows works only with read_csv() ?
What would be the equivalent for read_excel()?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is such an option.

Comment: Any suggestion how to just import up until certain row?

Comment: Something like `pd.read_excel(...).head(50)` will get you the first 50 rows, but of course it reads and discards, so I'm afraid it's not very helpful. Sorry.

Comment: `skip_footer`, as in the answer, ought to work (although, assumes you already know n).  Alternatively, unless the excel file is large (which usually they aren't else wouldn't be in a spreadsheet), @AmiTavory's suggestion ought to be fine.  Finally, `read_excel` is just a wrapper for py/excel libraries (I think `xlrd` by default).  If you really want fine control you'll need to use one of those libraries.  Here is a good starting point:  http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: @JohnE Very good points - useful to know.

Comment: @JohnE thanks for the info

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you know the number of rows in your Excel sheet, you can use the *skip_footer* parameter to read the first **n - skip_footer** rows of your file, where *n* is the total number of rows.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Usage:

```
data = pd.read_excel(filepath, header=0, parse_cols = "A:D", skip_footer=80)
```

Assuming your excel sheet has 100 rows, this line would parse the first 20 rows.

Comment: Funny, I guess that psychologically, "footer" is associated with something slim (like a physical page footer). Good answer.

Comment: Use `skipfooter` as `skip_footer` is deprecated since version 0.23.0

Answer (score 20):

As [noted in the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), as of pandas version 0.23, this is now a built-in option, and functions almost exactly as the OP stated.

The code

`data = pd.read_excel(filepath, header=0,  skiprows=4, nrows= 20, use_cols = "A:D")`

will now read the excel file, take data from the first sheet (default), skip 4 rows of data, *then* take the first line (i.e., the fifth line of the sheet) as the header, read the next 20 rows of data into the dataframe (lines 6-25), and only use the columns A:D. Note that use_cols is now the final option, as parse_cols is deprecated.

Comment: Is this bringing the entire file into memory before truncating to only 20 rows?

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to make (extend) [@Erol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35748574/5741205) bit more flexible.

Assuming that we DON'T know the total number of rows in the excel sheet:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(filepath)

# parsing first (index: 0) sheet
total_rows = xl.book.sheet_by_index(0).nrows

skiprows = 4
nrows = 20

# calc number of footer rows
# (-1) - for the header row
skipfooter = total_rows - nrows - skiprows - 1

df = xl.parse(0, skiprows=skiprows, skipfooter=skipfooter, parse_cols="A:D") \
       .dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

`.dropna(axis=1, how='all')` will drop all columns containing **only** `NaN`'s

Answer (score 0):

My Dear... Take it easy... Make it simple

`data = pd.read_excel(filepath, header=0,  skiprows=4, parse_cols = "A:D")`

`pd = pd[:20]`

I hope this is the answer to your question. Enjoy...

Comment: "My Dear... Take it easy... Make it simple" --> Be more respectful, no jugement, ex:
"Here is a simple one line solution:"