# How to convert n rows of xlsx to csv in Python while preserving date values

Tags: excel, python-2.7, csv, pandas, xlrd

I am trying to convert an xlsx file to one CSV file containing the header and another CSV file containing the actual data.
I have the following requirements:

1. Header does not start at first row but at row `start_line`.
2. Dates should not be considered as floats but in some string format.
3. I don't know the total number of rows or columns of the file beforehand. I also don't want to specify which column is a date.

Using `pandas` I get stuck at number 1.
I wanted to achieve this in two separate reads where I read from start_line to `start_line+1` and from `start_line+1` to the end.
However it seems like it is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747476/in-pandas-whats-the-equivalent-of-nrows-from-read-csv-to-be-used-in-read-ex) to read n lines from an offset. Below is the code I use to just get one file including the header.

```
import pandas as pd
def parse_excel(file,start_line,sheet,table):
    sh = pd.read_excel(file,sheet,skiprows=start_line)
    sh.to_csv("output.csv",sep='\t',encoding='utf-8',index=False)
```

Next I have tried this using `xlrd` but this library treats all dates as floats like in Excel. The only workaround here seems to [go through all individual cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727916/how-to-use-xlrd-xldate-as-tuple) which does not seem very efficient or well coded. What I have now:

```
import xlrd
def parse_excel(file,start_line,sheet,table):
    with xlrd.open_workbook(file) as wb:
        sh = wb.sheet_by_name(sheet)
        header_written = False
        with open('{0}.csv'.format(table),'wb') as csv_file:
            wr = csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter='\t')
            for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
                if not header_written and start_line == rownum:
                    with open('{0}_header.csv'.format(table),'wb') as header:
                        hwr = csv.writer(header,delimiter='\t')
                        hwr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
                        header_written = True
                elif header_written:
                    wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
```

Please point me to other solutions/libraries, show a workaround for either one of the above or explain why I should go for the `xlrd` workaround checking each individual cell.

Comment: You should be able to use the `header` parameter to set the line number for the column names. Combine this with `skip_rows` and I think that should take care of number 1. Use `parse_dates` to pass a list of the columns that are dates. To convert a numeric to date, I believe you will need to do this in a second line of code with `pd.to_datetime` and setting the `unit` parameter.

Comment: @TedPetrou `pandas` in fact treats the date exactly as I want it :). Can you show me how i can use the `header` parameter and extract the header? That would indeed solve my issue.

Comment: Use an integer for the row number where your column names reside. See the docs for more detail: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @TedPetrou I am quite unfamiliar with pandas. How should I then write the header to csv? Or will my output only contain the header when I use `to_csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all of your data is below your header row then following should work. Assuming the header row is at row `n` (indexing beginning at 0 not 1 like excel).

```
df = pd.read_excel('filepath', header=n)
df.head(0).to_csv('header.csv', index=False)
df.to_csv('output.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

Comment: Modified it to match my code. This indeed works, thanks.